# Magestore's Banner Slider not working properly(Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cms, home, banner-slider

### Magestore's Banner Slider not working properly(Magento 1.9)

I have added Magestore's Banner slider extension version 2 in my project.

In my CMS Home page I have added the code,

```
{{block type="bannerslider/bannerslider" name="bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml"}}
```

But still it is not getting displayed

Comment: Questions about 3rd party modules are offtopic on Magento SE. I suggest you contact Magestore directly as your question will most likely be closed

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, I think this question is not off topic. The way he has asked, its look like off topic. But please check my answer its not off topic. So I think we have to reopen this question.

Comment: @AshishJagnani I agree. However, without providing more information (such as the error in the log saying the block is not whitelisted), it's a shot in a dark and thus can be considered as offtopic. Glad your answer fixed his issue though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be permission issue only.

You need to give permission from admin to your block `bannerslider/bannerslider`

1. Go to `Admin -> System -> Permission -> Blocks`
2. `Add New Block` and add block name `bannerslider/bannerslider`
3. Set `isAllowed` to `Yes`
4. `Save Block` and clear the `cache`.